# React Native animation value 'auto'

Tags: react-native

```
const heightAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current
const heightInterpolate = heightAnim.interpolate({
inputRange: [0,1],
outputRange: ['auto',500],
})
```

> The above code not working because error invalid pattern. 'auto' is
> String and 500 is number.

I try to set

```
const value2 = 500,
outputRange: ['auto',value2],
```

> but as I expected it didn't work

How can set Value of animated to 'auto'?

Comment: I think here you can't mix string and number.

outputRange is an array of numbers or strings

Comment: I know that it is not possible to combine Number and String, so I am asking if there is any other way to achieve it. OutputRange table can can only have one type (all in Numbers or all in Strings).

Comment: i think you can use LayoutAnimation just before the state change that causes your component's height to change. if you are confused i can put my suggestion as answer

Comment: Can you write an example please?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example using LayoutAnimation

```
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      if (UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
        UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
      }
    }
    .....
    const App = () => {
       .....
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
            setExpanded(!expanded);
          }}
        >
          <Text>Press me to {expanded ? "collapse" : "expand"}!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View
          style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: expanded ? "auto" : 500 }}
        >
          <Text>Test</Text>
          <Text>Test</Text>
          <Text>Test</Text>
          <Text>Test</Text>
          <Text>Test</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      ....
```

---

We can call **ConfigureNext** with 3 **presets**

1. LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut
2. LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear
3. LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring

You can even create your custom confige

```
ConfigureNext({ duration: 700, update: { type: 'spring', springDamping: 0.4 },})
```

Check [Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation) for more information

Comment: This way doesn't work

Comment: Can you explain what animation you want? because the code above is trying to expand and shrink the view height